# How to search for an exact phrase in Google search?

Tags: google-search

In the 2020s, with Google using machine learning and other fancy stuff to find search results, how can I search for an exact phrase, and ***only that exact phrase***, in Google search?

I'm aware that enclosing a phrase in double quotes is supposed to search for that exact phrase. However, as at August 2022 this no longer seems to work.

For example, I was searching for a particular Azure command, `"az acr run"` and I was getting lots of results like "run az acr build", "az acr build is always failing", "unable to run az acr check-health". `az acr build` and `az acr check-health` are completely different commands from the one I'm interested in, `az acr run`.

Is there anything better than enclosing a phrase in double quotes or is that the best we can expect?

Comment: What about using “+az +acr +build” for the query text?

Comment: @Giacomo1968: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it but the results said "Results for +az +acr +run (without quotes)".  The results were less accurate than those for "az acr run" (without the + signs).

Comment: Can't reproduce here.